# swiftUI transitions: Scale from some frame - like iOS Homescreen is doing when opening an App

Tags: ios, swiftui

How do I get the effect in a translation, that iOS home screen does when opening an App: It scales the App to fullscreen, starting from the App-icon on the home screen?

In my code, I have the icon-frame (`CGRect`) with position, width and height and I have the final frame. Is there a way to (probably combine some) transitions to get a scaling from the icon-frame to the final frame?

I get somewhat similar with:

```
view.transition(AnyTransition.scale(scale: 0, anchor: UnitPoint.trailing))
```

Which scales from zero to the original size, starting from trailing center position.
It's only close as:

- it scales from zero instead of the size of the original icon
- it starts from a fixed point (trailing, center) but I'd like to let it start from where the icon is.

Just to be sure: It must be a transition as the view is newly created and dropped. I tried with keeping the view and just change its opacity to show/hide it. With many other problems like not getting the reverse animation, when the view disappears.

Comment: on the iOS home screen the icon is always visible, then scales when you open it. In your example you want it to be hidden and then scale up from a specific scaling factor? Your first point can be solved by putting a different value for `scale`.. like `0.5` for example so it scales from 50% the size to 100% - full size, how are your icons organised? In a grid like on the iOS home screen?

Comment: Thank you, I found an answer from your question.  

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a demo of idea how such effect could be done with combined transitions... (positions and sizes are hardcoded for demo simplicity - they can be read with geometry reader, alignment guides or anchor preferences, and actually do not affect the transition usage idea, also animation can be configured)

Demo:

[image: SwiftUI view from button]

```
struct TestRisingView: View {

    let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds

    @State var showingView = false
    @State var btFrame: CGRect = .zero

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            ZStack {
                Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)

                self.activatingButton(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 30, width: 60, height: 40))
                self.activatingButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.screen.maxX - 80, y: 30, width: 60, height: 40))
                self.activatingButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.screen.maxX - 80, y: self.screen.maxY - 60, width: 60, height: 40))
                self.activatingButton(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: self.screen.maxY - 60, width: 60, height: 40))

                if self.showingView {
                    self.topView
                        .zIndex(1)
                        .transition(
                            AnyTransition.scale(scale: 0.12).combined(with:
                            AnyTransition.offset(x: self.btFrame.origin.x - g.size.width/2.0,
                                                 y: self.btFrame.origin.y - g.size.height/2.0))
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func activatingButton(frame: CGRect) -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                self.btFrame = frame
                self.showingView.toggle()
            }
        }) {
            Text("Tap")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.yellow)
        }
        .position(frame.origin)
    }

    var topView: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I‘ll do the math to get from origin frame to final frame for scale and offset and edit my question to show the final result.

Comment: One more thing: The combined transition works only with explicit animation. I tried with implicit and the green rectangle was jumping around by the offset. Seems to be a bug in SwiftUI (anybody the URL where I can file this?)
And in the meantime - rewrite code to work with explicit animations.
Thanks again for your answer. I'd never found this otherwise.

Comment: Not sure what's happened in 9 months, but the open animation open is immediate now.

Answer (score 3):

The above sample code should give you an idea on scaling an image

```swift
struct ImageCustomScaling: View {
    // image to be scaled
    var scaleImage: Image

    // scale ratio
    var scaleTo: Double

    @State private var start = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            scaleImage
                .font(.title)
                .scaleEffect(self.start ? CGFloat(scaleTo) : 1)
                .opacity(self.start ? 1 : 0)
                .animation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 25, damping: 5, initialVelocity: 10).delay(0.9))

        }
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .onAppear {
            self.start = true
        }
    }

}
```

Above can be called by something like below

```swift
ImageCustomScaling(scaleImage: Image(systemName: "cloud.fill"), scaleTo: 5 )
```

Added animation modifier to give visual cue.  You can change it to meet your needs.

Comment: Hi, yes this is the idea with `onAppear` instead of transitions. The problem: When disappearing, it does not animate. When adding the `onDisappear` and set the `start` back to `false` it does not animate. I checked the code, and SwiftUI runs the closure in `onDisappear` but does not call the modifiers any more. And I can understand this approach: The view disappears anyway, so why decorate it?

Comment: so you need the animation should happen in reverse order  as well when the view disappears.

Answer (score 3):

Now in 2021 we finally got an answer from Apple. `matchedGeometryEffect` solves this problem elegantly and easily.

Here is a little screenshot of what it does:

[image: Demo of transition using matchedGeometryEffect]

And here is the code for this demo:

```
struct Stackoverflow: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State private var shown: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                shown.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Tap Me!\nI'm a red square.")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
            .background(
                Color.red
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "1", in: namespace, properties: .frame))
        
            Spacer()
            if shown {
                Color.clear
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "1", in: namespace, properties: .size)
                    .border(Color.gray)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
    }
}

struct Stackoverflow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Stackoverflow()
    }
}
```

[Check here on swift-lab.com](https://swiftui-lab.com/matchedgeometryeffect-part1/?unapproved=1164&moderation-hash=94a476bad750bd959d1d704fc4c6cefa#comment-1164), for more information and explanation on how to use `matchedGeometryEffect`.