# Animate Image from Thumbnail to Full Screen

Tags: swiftui

Would it be possible to replicate the behaviour of the iOS Photos app, when opening a detailView of a photo when the user taps the photo it expands to fill the screen - in SwiftUI.

I can open the photo in a new view over the current view, however I can't seem to manage how to animate the image in the view expanding from it's current location to full screen - is this even possible when it's nested in stacks?

Here's a basic version of my UI:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            BannerView()
                .padding()
            Text("Title")
        }

    }
}

struct BannerView: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "rectangle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        // Enbiggen image
                }
            }
            VStack {
                Text("Text")
                Text("Text 1")
                Text("Text 2")
            }
        }
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
    }

}
```

So when the user taps the image in BannerView, it should animate from it's current size to fill the screen.

The only way I can manage it in my head is to hide a duplicate image over the Bannerview image from within ContentView and animate that visible then to scale to full screen, but how would I detect the location and size of the Image within BannerView?

Comment: The approach in the this topic [swiftUI transitions: Scale from some frame - like iOS Homescreen is doing when opening an App](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59408179/12299030) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the image to become full screen with a simple zoom animation by adding a `State` for the aspect ratio of the rectangle

```
struct BannerView: View {
    @State var contentMode = ContentMode.fit

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "rectangle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: contentMode)
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.contentMode = ContentMode.fill
                        }
                }
            }
            VStack {
                Text("Text")
                Text("Text 1")
                Text("Text 2")
            }
        }
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
    }
}
```